# iOS Safari Mobile: Doesn't show huge images in correct size

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

When I display an image with a width of 1600px it's shown correctly. But when I display an image that has, for example 1920px width, Safari displays it way smaller.

I use:

```
<!-- in the header -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />

<!-- correct -->
<img src="content/dummy/brand_backgroud_1600_1.jpg" alt="">

<!-- to small -->
<img src="content/dummy/brand_backgroud_1920_1.jpg" alt="">
```

How can I fix this, without setting the overall width in the meta-tag?

This happens on both, iPhone and iPad with iOS 5.1

**Edit:**
Even with this most simple html-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="content/dummy/brand_backgroud_1920_1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="content/dummy/brand_backgroud_1600_1.jpg" alt="">


</body>
</html>
```

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but safari is probably trying to be "helpful" to the user.

Comment: Drawing HUGE images might be exploitable in a mobile device. I think that's just because safari is trying to protect user, battery power, etc... It's also written [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ipad-3-benchmark-review,3156-5.html)

Comment: Thanks, I can see that. But what's really bothering me is, that it's not displayed in the right relation to other content elements. It's way smaller than 1600px image. I could live with a down sampled version, but in the right relation to other elements. And also the iPad3 has 2048px width, so why not use it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach might be to set the image width to be "100%", height to be "auto". That way all images, regardless of their pixel width, will appear to be the full width of their parent container. This is actually a neat trick to support Retina too.

Edit: Ok, now I understand what you are saying. You want the user to see the full-sized 1600 or 1920 images, and you do NOT want iOS to scale it.

Edit #2: So I tried a couple different things - you are correct. iOS appears to be "scaling" images that do not have width or height explicitly set, when the image size is above a certain px value. When you do explicitly set them, they work as expected. That seems to be your only solution at this point.

```
<img src="image_1600.jpg" alt="" style="width: 1600px; height: auto" />
<img src="image_1920.jpg" alt="" style="width: 1920px; height: auto" />
```

Comment: I thought about that, too. The thing is, if you don't know how big the image is, you don't know the size of the container. So, the image might be scaled.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (see updated question), or did I miss something?

Comment: @insertusernamehere it shouldn't look like that. That is very odd. Could you post the original images somewhere so I can take a deeper look? A wild guess: It may be that in the META information on the image itself, it is specifying a DPI of some number.

Comment: I've put them into the dropbox. They are both downsampled (from a much wider image) in Photoshop and than saved for web and devices as JPG: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1336931/_Stackoverflow/image_1920.jpg and https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1336931/_Stackoverflow/image_1600.jpg

Comment: Thanks for all your effort. I'm happy, that it seems to be an iOS typical behavior.